# Does Callable interface is also used to create thread like Runnable??

Tags: java, multithreading

Does Callable interface is also used to create thread like Runnable??

As I have used it with executer framework so it work like same as runnable.
I have seen only two traditional ways to create a Thread so far till now.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Runnable and Callable are similar, they are both ways to specify a task which can be performed by an Executor. Callable exists for tasks that need to return a result.

Runnable and Callable are not used to "create a thread". Defining objects using these interfaces lets you keep separate the specification of what task you need performed from the specification of what infrastructure should perform the task. When you create a Runnable or Callable and pass it to an Executor, the executor can do things like hand it off to an existing thread drawn from a pool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or execute it in the current thread ([SingleTheadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor)). There isn't a requirement that a Runnable or Callable needs to create its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a `Callable<T>` like a `Runnable` by wrapping it in a `FutureTask<T>` (which implements `Runnable`). You can retrieve the returned value by calling the `<T> get()` function of the `FutureTask<T>` you wrapped the callable with.